# how to get back in navigation view

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone application. i am doing an application that consist of image picker and image view. i am displaying the  image in imageview by selecting the image in image picker .. what i need is afetr 3 seconds i have to go back imagepicker how can i done this please give code for that

Answer (score 0):

You want to create an NSTimer object.

```
NSTimer *theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(pictureTimerFired:) 
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
```

Where the target selector has a signature like:

```
- (void) pictureTimerFired:(NSTimer*)theTimer {

NSLog(@"Timer fired, closing picture");
```

}

You would remove the imageView in the opposite way you added it.  i.e. it depends if it was added as a modal view or subview etc.